# It shouldn't take a fool to see that I believe. Meaning

Tags: meaning, phrases

"It shouldn't take a fool to see that I believe".  Trying to understand this phrase from  Iron Maiden's song. I can't catch the meaning of it. It shouldn't be "No need to be fool to see that I believe" or should it?

Comment: Remember that song lyrics are often written to better fit the rhythm of a song than to be grammatically precise. However, in this case, I think the original is better written than your alternative, even from a purely grammatical perspective.

Comment: I still don't understand the meaning of it, completely don't

Comment: Usually one would say something like "It doesn't take a rocket scientist to understand X" implying that one does not need the genius that rocket scientists supposedly possess to understand X.  One would expect fools to misunderstand X, so why would you take a fool for this task?  But it is a song lyric so....

Comment: Maybe : "Even a fool sees that I believe"?

Answer (score 2):

> It shouldn't take a ladder to see over the hedge.

**take** = require.

The hedge is not so tall that a ladder would be required  in order to see over it.

The relationship of **ladder** here to **hedge** is clear. A hedge can have *height*. Ladders allow us to climb to a height.

However, in your quoted lyric, we can only guess at the relationship between **fool** and **believing**, and it doesn't take a genius to see that guessing would be off-topic for this site.